# Is possible to see battery status of a bluetooth audio device if is not used for calls?

Tags: battery, bluetooth, audio

I have bluetooth audio receiver which shows its battery level in Bluetooth settings. But when I disable Phone calls for this device, can't see battery level anymore.

It's even possible to see it without using the device for calls?

[image]